# How do you customize the admin bar for buddypress?

Tags: css, buddypress, navigation

I would like to update the coding on the wp-admin-bar. Since its positioned absolute, I would like to put a div around it that is relative and or just in a normal div.

Or, I see you can hide the bar, does anyone have link structure for the admin bar?

Ex:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.siteurl.com/members/%username%/">My Account</a></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm not a buddypress user, so just to be clear for the sake of anyone reading, is this admin bar specific to buddypress? And if so, you're looking for suggestions on hooks to modify this admin bar's output right(or possibly just the links)?

Comment: Yes, correct. Im basically looking for something similar to the   <?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>. Where it will output the list in an <ul>.

Right now the HTML in the wp admin bar isnt ideal, your only real option is to position it absolutely to the screen. Since by default it is included in the footer.

I guess my question should of been how do you build a custom buddypress wp-admin-bar

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the functions in this file:

buddypress/bp-core/bp-core-adminbar.php

That's where you'll find what you're looking for most likely.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is open up buddypress/bp-core/bp-core-buddybar.php and then find the functions that make up the list items. Once you spot them you can figure out what's what and then copy the whole function of a list item to your functions.php in your child theme. Once you have it there you can edit it how you want and you won't have to worry about redoing it every time you update. If you're not using a child theme then you can edit the functions in their original spot but you'll have to redo it everytime you update buddypress. If you're just looking to change the position property of a div you can do that through css by targeting the item in your child themes style sheet.